# Cocoa API Image Manipulation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

Is there any way to do simple image manipulation like adjusting brightness, contrast, exposure, etc. using Cocoa? Something like NSImage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to present UI to allow the user to make these kinds of modifications, look at [ImageKit](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/ImageViews/ImageViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004907-CH4-SW9).

Answer (score 5):

You want [Core Image](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/coreimage.html), I think.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at Core Image?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out the [CoreImage FunHouse](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/FunHouse/index.html) example.  It pretty much shows you how to use most of what CoreImage can do.